# How can I display the value and/or type of an fstar expression?

Tags: fstar, fstar-mode

I'm going through the fstar tutorial using the emacs fstar-mode. Is there a way to evaluate an expression or its type?

What I'm looking for is an equivalent to Lean's #check or #eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fstar-mode.el, the emacs mode for F*, you can do

- C-c C-s C-e: to evaluate an expression
- C-c C-s C-d: to show the type and docs of an identifier

These and other utilities can be found from the F* menu in the menu bar of emacs when running fstar-mode.el